# Cannot install Ubuntu 11.04 or 11.10 on Acer Aspire M3970

Tags: system-installation, 11.10, 11.04, live-cd, aspire

I cannot install Ubuntu 11.04 or 11.10 on my new machine, not in 32-bit or 64-bit, and not from CD or USB drive.

I tried to unplug all devices connected to USB, but nothing changes.

```
[ 15.383691] sd 7:0:0:3: [sdg] Attached SCSI removeable disk.
```

Then the installation or Live image booting does nothing more. Irritatingly, Ubuntu runs on every other machine that I own -- just not this new PC.

What can I do to get this running?

For comparison's sake, 10.04 LTS seems to work in every way. Why won't 11.04 or 11.10 work? Is there possibly a bug in the installer?

Answer (score 2):

At boot time, try to press <kbd>F6</kbd> and add one, two or these 3 commands: `acpi=off noapic noalpic`

That is:

```
acpi=off noapic noalpic
```

or

```
acpi=off noalpic
```

or

```
acpi=off noapic
```

or

```
noapic noalpic
```

or

```
acpi=off
```

or

```
noapic
```

or

```
noalpic
```

Comment: Can you please [edit] this answer to explain why readers should follow your advice and how it might work to resolve this question?  "Do this" answers miss a great opportunity to educate and empower thousands of future researchers.

Comment: This has to do with power management on laptops. I will edit to explain asap.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to change the BIOS? The CD should be the first BOOT device.

To access the BIOS menu on the Acer, you press <kbd>F2</kbd> when the BIOS message is shown after you turn on the computer. Then, you can navigate the BIOS with the arrow keys and change the BOOT device. The on-screen help will tell you how to change it, and how to save it.

The first element should be CD or DVD. HD stands for Hard Drive and should be second, or third...